# insert blank rows into a matrix with location depending on a logical statement

Tags: matlab

I have an array with the first column 'hour of year' the other 13 columns are random measurements. There are some hours missing within the first column. I want to insert rows of '9999' where the hours are missing, whilst maintaining the first column as the following hour.

```
A=[1,3,4,76,88,3,54,6,33...;    
2,54,3,656,8,9999,65,3,4,77...;
5,34,3,6,77,4,234,9999.....]
```

I would like this to become:

```
A = [1,3,4,76,88,3,54,6,33...;  
2,54,3,656,8,9999,65,3,4,77...;   
3,9999,9999,9999,9999......   
4,9999,9999,9999,9999.....   
5,34,3,6,77,4,234,9999.....]
```

all the way to 8760

Some of the data is missing the first hour.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is recommended that you post example data that is possible to use directly, _as is_. It is much easier to help if it is possible to just copy-paste. In this case, the same number of columns in each row would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to @RobertP's answer, but avoids some steps and is slightly faster:

```
B = [ (1:8760).' 9999*ones(8760,size(A,2)-1) ];
B(A(:,1),2:end) = A(:,2:end);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
%% The example matrix:
A =
      1      3      4     76     88      3     54      6
      2     54      3    656      8   9999     65      3
      5     34      3      6     77      4    234   9999

B = zeros(8760, size(A,2));
B(A(:,1),:) = A;

B(B(:,1)==0,2:end) = 9999;
B(:,1) = 1:8760   % (Used 1:5 in my example below)

B =  
      1      3      4     76     88      3     54      6
      2     54      3    656      8   9999     65      3
      3   9999   9999   9999   9999   9999   9999   9999
      4   9999   9999   9999   9999   9999   9999   9999
      5     34      3      6     77      4    234   9999
```